# 403 Forbidden Error using services.users.List() method in C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, directoryservices

403 Forbidden using users.List() method, Service Account in Google Cloud:

Hello iám using these nuggets:

```
<PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth" Version="1.60.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1" Version="1.60.0.3064" />
```

code:

```
 ServiceAccountCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(basePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
            .CreateScoped(DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly)
            .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
    }


    DirectoryService service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "nombre"
    });

 var request = service.Users.List();
    request.Customer = "customerId";
    var users = request.Execute();
```

I already added the necessary roles in the google cloud console and I send it the necessary scopes, but it still gives me a 403 forbidden error, what could it be?

Comment: First set up Domain Wide Delegation for the service account. Note: your service account must impersonate a user. Then use `.CreateScoped(scopes).CreateWithUser(user_email)`